# What is the 'working directory' when cron executes a job?

Tags: directory, cron, path, cd-command

I have a script that works when I run it from the command line, but when I schedule it with `cron` I get errors that it cannot find files or commands.  My question is twofold:

1. When I schedule a cron job using `crontab -e`, does it use my user ID as the basis for its permissions?  Or does it use a cron user ID of some sort and its related permissions?
2. When a cron job is launched, what is the working directory?  Is it the directory where I specify the script to run, or a different directory?

Here is my cron job:

```
15 7 * * * /home/xxxx/Documents/Scripts/email_ip_script.sh
```

Here is the actual script:

```
vIP_ADDR="`curl automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp`"
echo "$vIP_ADDR"
sed "s/IPADDR/$vIP_ADDR/g" template.txt > emailmsg.txt
ssmtp XXXXX@gmail.com < emailmsg.txt
```

Here are the errors I get when I view the `mail` message produced by `cron`:

```
sed: can't read template.txt: No such file or directory
/home/xxxx/Documents/Scripts/email_ip_script.sh: line 15: ssmtp: command not found
```

It cannot find the `template.txt` but it resides in the same directory as the script.  It also cannot run `ssmtp`, but I can as my user.  What am I missing to get this to work properly?

Answer (score 244, accepted):

Add `cd /home/xxxx/Documents/Scripts/` if you want your job to run in that directory. There's no reason why cron would change to that particular directory. Cron runs your commands in your home directory.

As for `ssmtp`, it might not be in your default `PATH`. Cron's default path is implementation-dependent, so check your man page, but in all likelihood `ssmtp` is in `/usr/sbin` which is not in your default `PATH`, only root's.

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
15 7 * * * cd /home/xxxx/Documents/Scripts && ./email_ip_script.sh
```

Comment: @Giles - Thanks, would `cron` have it's own `PATH` or can I check my user's `PATH`?  I set ssmtp up to have it's own `user` and `wheel` permission thinking it would allow anyone to use it (including cron).  If it helps Im on CENTOS 6.2

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur Your problem isn't that you aren't allowed to use `ssmtp`, but that your cron job doesn't find any executable called `ssmtp` because it's not in your `PATH`. There's no such thing as “your user's `PATH`”; this is a per-process setting, not a per-user setting. You can set the path for all your cron jobs by putting a `PATH=…` line in your crontab.

Comment: I had to add MAILTO='XXXX@gmail.com' as well to get it working along with PATH setup. Wierd but it worked for me.

Comment: For ssmtp one can use; `´which ssmtp´ ...`

Comment: @FredrickGauss [Make that `type ssmtp`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Comment: Yeah that does not work, you just get `Command 'cd' not found in /usr/bin, (...)`.

Answer (score 41):

If your cronjob is a bash script, the following will CD to the location of your script (assuming that you're using absolute path in your cron definition):

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")";
```

Comment: The question was where is the default working directory. I'm now investigating the results of a command that run in the default working directory, and this answer doesn't help me investigate that.

Comment: @Flimm it sorts of answer the question by implying the current directory is not the directory the script runs in

Answer (score 19):

To answer question 1: if you run `crontab -e` as your own user the jobs will be scheduled in that user's crontab and will thus run with the permissions of that user.

But you need to consider that the jobs will run in a non-interactive shell meaning that the $PATH might be different from the one you have when running the script from the command line.

It is best to always use full paths in scripts, especially if you plan to schedule them via at/cron etc.

I would also recommend using full paths to all files to avoid exactly the problems you see.

To prevent race conditions and other security issues you should also use `mktemp` to make sure the file you read is not modified by anything outside your script.

So I'd change the script to something like:

```
vIP_ADDR="`curl automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp`"
echo "$vIP_ADDR"
mail_msg=`/bin/mktemp`
/bin/sed "s/IPADDR/$vIP_ADDR/g" /home/xxxx/Documents/Scripts/template.txt > $mailmsg
/path/to/ssmtp XXXXX@gmail.com < $mailmsg
/bin/rm $mailmsg
```

Answer (score 8):

`cron` runs each user's scheduled jobs as that user. This should be enough for us to work out that it runs your scripts relative to your home directory.

If you need it to run from a different location, simply use `cd` in your script to go to that location.

`ssmtp` is probably not in `cron`'s default PATH (it is set to be very narrow by design on most platforms). You can either specify the full path to `ssmtp` in your script, or you can explicitly set PATH in a) your crontab file, which will be available to all your scripts, or b) in each script.

Answer (score 4):

Some people have hinted or linked at it but the best way to find out since I can't find it in the man docs for my distro is just add this to a cron

```
* * * * * echo "$PWD" > /tmp/lolcronjobs
```

Then cat out lolcronjobs to see what your working directory is. The same works for finding $PATH and other environment variables.

Comment: You can also run `pwd > /tmp/pwd.txt`