# Pushing to a Git repo from shell script

Tags: shell-script, cron

I'm trying to commit/push changes to a remote Git server with the below sample code:

```
#!/bin/sh

USER='username'
REPO='/home/'${USER}'/Sites/git/bitbucket/kb'
COMMIT_TIMESTAMP=`date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'`
DATELOG=`date +'%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S'`
LOG="/tmp/${DATELOG}.txt"

MKDOCS=`which mkdocs`
GIT=`which git`
NOTIFY=`which notify-send`

# Only proceed if we have a valid repo.
if [ ! -d ${REPO}/.git ]; then
  echo "${REPO} is not a valid git repo! Aborting..." >> ${LOG}
  exit 0
else
  echo "${REPO} is a valid git repo! Proceeding..." >> ${LOG}
fi

cd ${REPO}
${MKDOCS} build --clean >> ${LOG}
${GIT} add --all . >> ${LOG}
${GIT} commit -m "Automated commit on ${COMMIT_TIMESTAMP}" >> ${LOG}
${GIT} push git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git master >> ${LOG}

# Depends on libnotify
${NOTIFY} 'KB notification' 'Changes were pushed to Bitbucket.' --icon=dialog-information >> ${LOG}
```

If I invoke the shell script manually (e.g. `./commit.sh`) it works immediately. On the contrary, when triggered via a cron job everything works just fine until the `git push` which then never seems to be triggered for some odd reason.

Here's my crontab line:

```
*/20 * * * * /home/username/Sites/git/repo/commit.sh
```

And some verbosity for `git push`

```
09:53:32.732216 git.c:349               trace: built-in: git 'push' 'git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git' 'master'
09:53:32.732514 run-command.c:341       trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@bitbucket.org' 'git-receive-pack '\''username/repo.git'\'''
09:53:39.665197 run-command.c:341       trace: run_command: 'pack-objects' '--all-progress-implied' '--revs' '--stdout' '--thin' '--delta-base-offset' '--progress'
09:53:39.665526 exec_cmd.c:134          trace: exec: 'git' 'pack-objects' '--all-progress-implied' '--revs' '--stdout' '--thin' '--delta-base-offset' '--progress'
09:53:39.666778 git.c:349               trace: built-in: git 'pack-objects' '--all-progress-implied' '--revs' '--stdout' '--thin' '--delta-base-offset' '--progress'
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 4.23 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git
   0ef4905..91437d0  master -> master
```

How come `git push` would be triggered only when the script is invoked manually and not when run via the crontab?

Comment: Did `cron` send you any e-mail?

Comment: It could rely on environment variables like `$HOME` or `$USER`.

Comment: cron is not the culprit it seems as the cron job is executed and logged just fine under `/var/log/syslog` e.g. `Aug 31 22:44:01 laptop CRON[9364]: (username) CMD (/home/username/Sites/git/repo/commit.sh)`

Comment: Did you find out any solution? I have the same problem. (btw, I don't know where to look for email sent by deamon. Do I have to do anything to receive it? In Mac, I receive it automatically in a folder, but not on Ubuntu)

Answer (score 6):

What director(ies|y) are you looking to do this in? It is not clear from you script. Try going into the directory<sup>1</sup>, something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

GIT=`which git`
REPO_DIR=/home/username/Sites/git/repo/
cd ${REPO_DIR}
${GIT} add --all .
${GIT} commit -m "Test commit"
${GIT} push git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git master
```

Or you can do a `git add --all /path/to/git/repo/files`.

**Edit**:

Running a script from the command line is not necessarily the same as running it from cron; see this Q&A: [What is the 'working directory' when cron executes a job](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38951/4252), especially [Gilles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38956/4252).

<sup>1</sup>Some ideas on how to [check if a command succeeded](https://askubuntu.com/a/29379)

Comment: That's going to be hilarious when the unchecked `cd` call fails. `set -e` or check the result of the `cd`.

Comment: Just a suggestion to do `cd`; checking is left to the user (-: Great suggestion nonetheless!

Comment: That's the reason I think. I asked OP to check any mail sent by `cron` daemon for him to make sure. However, there are 2 problems with this script: 1. what if there is no `git` installed? 2. what if `cd` fails?

Comment: Not to mention the issues with the use of `which`, http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/4252

Comment: @KM. The script lives in the same directory as the files/dirs to be committed. As I said in the summary, this is only a code sample, the full script is a tad bit more advanced.

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk checking that `git` is installed or `cd` works fine is not in the equation here. I 100% agree it makes the script more solid but this is not what's failing here. Only the `git push` is.

Comment: @KM. I didn't know for `which`. Thanks, will refactor.

Comment: @anavarre: ok, it's a shame that you just didn't show us your whole script at the beginning. We try to help you here. It's also a shame that didn't check mail from `cron` as I asked you to.

Comment: @ Arkadiusz Drabczyk Thought this would derail the conversation by pointing out all the wrong things I did like `which` or not enough checks (is git available? etc.) instead of answering the `git push` issue. Edited the original post in the hopes it helps understanding what's wrong better.

Comment: I didn't ask you for `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk I didn't get what you were asking earlier but I think I do now. Found `Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights` with `mailx`. Odd, since the user running the script doesn't have any issue with perms since ssh-add is run at startup...

Comment: Is the above crontab for the same user that is running the script? If not, that might be a for this error. Also,  how is  `ssh-add`  run for this script?

Comment: @KM. yes, same user exactly, thus my surprise. `ssh-add` is run at startup time for this user, which never requires me authenticating again for SSH/Git connections, at least in the context of the prompt. Looks like via a script things might be different.

Comment: Might be time for sanity checks. Ensure keys are in place, with proper permissions, and they match those on bitbucket. Also, try `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git push git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git master` and see/post what you get.

Comment: @KM. - `git push` works well interactively. So are my SSH keys. It's only in the context of the shell script that it fails with the above permission denied issue. I've edited the original post for you to see the result of the verbose/trace mode when run interactively. The same verbose message fails with a permission denied issue when run via the script. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and that is how I fixed it:

1. First, try to find out why what is the error of your push. You can get the error log by adding `2>&1` at the end of your script. In your case it would be:

   ```
   ${GIT} push git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git master >> ${LOG} 2>&1
   ```
2. Several reason can cause your push is not working from within your shell. Check these criteria:

   - your user name and password is Stored/Cached correctly. You can push to git URL directly including your User/Pass just for test (DON'T forget to remove them). e.g.:

     ```
     ${GIT} push --repo https://YOUR_USER_NAME:YOUR_PASSWORD@bitbucket.org/repo.git
     ```
   - Make sure Git is not complaining about SSL (You can *temporarily* ignore it by adding this command before your `push` in your script:

     ```
     export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1
     ```
3. In case you are not if `git push` is executed in the right directory, you can go to your desired directory before your script is executed by adding pre-step to your `cron` job as follow:

   ```
   */20 * * * * cd /home/'${USER}'/Sites/git/bitbucket/kb && /home/username/Sites/git/repo/commit.sh
   ```