# Cronjob does not work on Linux Mint 20

Tags: shell-script, shell, linux-mint, cron

This is what my crontab looks like:

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /home/rathindu/assignment/test.sh
```

The test.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir new
```

The script is not running. But if I just open the terminal and invoke the script without using crontab it works perfectly.

When I inspect the CRON syslog

```
CRON[6909]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output
```

This is what I get.

Comment: That's because your cron job had some output and cron wanted to send your account an email with its content. I have a feeling it's trying to tell you that the `mkdir` command failed.

Comment: What is that you recommend me to do about this. I am really new to linux.

Comment: use absolute path to `/bin/mkdir /path/to/destination/new`

Comment: Thank you. It really helped.

Comment: @αғsнιη is there anyway that instead of using absolute paths each time, just have kind of a path variable to current folder and then the rest can just be relative paths as it is. In simple terms I am looking for a way to tell cron that this is the current path to the folder, and all the other paths are relative to that particular path. Is that possible?

Comment: @smooth-felix yes, switch to that directory before you want do things `cd /path/to/where/your/stuff/is/there`, but it's also better to use absolute path for any commands you are using because `crontab` has its own environment and maybe some commands it will still not able to find if you don't provide the full path

Comment: @αғsнιη Thank you for your generous tips and advice. really appreciate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the 'working directory' when cron executes a job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38951/what-is-the-working-directory-when-cron-executes-a-job)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as  @αғsнιη suggested in the comment, I replaced every relative path with an absolute path and it did worked perfectly. there was no need to use `/bin/mkdir/` it just worked fine with simple `mkdir`.
But the paths to the files had to be changed to their absolute paths

```
mkdir new
```

had to be changed to

```
mkdir /home/username/folder/new
```

And regarding the `CRON[6909]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output`
It was just a matter of installing a local mailbox:

```
apt-get install postfix
```

and then the mails can be found at:

```
tail -f /var/mail/<cron user>
```

Comment: You will find the directory `new` in your home directory, where the first instance of your cron job created it. You can capture cron output in a log file rather than having it emailed to you, usually by appending `> logfile 2>&1` to the command.

Comment: Your previous version was actually creating the new directory into your home directory which is the cron's initial `$PWD`.