# How can I use $(pwd) in a bash script run via crontab?

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron

I have a script named `Run_at_startup.sh`, which contains the following line:

```
/bin/bash "$(pwd)/Testing_3.sh"
```

If I manually run `Run_at_startup.sh`, `Testing_3.sh` will be run properly. However, if `Run_at_startup.sh` is run via `crontab`, `Testing_3.sh` will not be run. Obviously, the problem lies in `$(pwd)`. So, is it impossible to use `$(pwd)` in a script run via `crontab`? If so, what can be used instead of `$(pwd)`?

Comment: If your script assumes that you are in a particular directory before you run the script, make sure that your cron job first uses `cd` to change to that directory.  I'm just guessing that this is the issue, so I'm not turning this into a real answer.

Comment: See also [What is the 'working directory' when cron executes a job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38951) which your question may be a duplicate of.

Comment: Why are you using `$(pwd)`, why would you need this to be dynamic instead of using the actual path?

Comment: @Kusalananda, after referring to your link, I found a simple solution. Please read my answer below.

Comment: @terdon,   
Next time, if the full absolute path is different, I will have to modify the script. If I forget to modify it, it will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After referring to the link posted by Kusalananda, I found the following solution:

```
/bin/bash "$(dirname "$0")/Testing_3.sh"
```

**$(dirname "$0")** works fine in a bash script run via crontab.

Comment: It still isn't clear why you don't just specify the full absolute path to `Testing_3.h`.

Comment: @Henrik supports the community,   
Next time, if the full absolute path is different, I will have to modify the script. If I forget to modify it, it will fail.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run a script that lies in the current working directory of the process invoking it, just use `./that-script`.

`"$(pwd)/that-script"` in POSIX-like shells (and `cron` should invoke a POSIX-like shell to parse the commands lines) is a poorer version of `"$PWD/that-script"`. Poorer because it has to run an extra process and also because `$(...)` strips **all** trailing newline characters, so it won't work if the path to the current working directory stored in `$PWD` ends in newline characters.

The difference between `./that-script` and `"$PWD/that-script"` (which will be expanded to `/path/to/working/directory/that-script`) is that the former is a relative path and the latter in an absolute path. In either case, if `that-script` is not to be found in the current working directory of the shell process that `cron` invokes to parse that command line, that will fail.

By default jobs in your `crontab` are generally started in your home directory.

If `that-script` is not in that directory, you'd use `/actual/path/to/that-script`. If it were also important that the script be run with its current working also directory being `/actual/path/to`, you'd do:

```
cd /actual/path/to && ./that-script
```

Or:

```
cd /actual/path/to && "$PWD/that-script"
```

If you want to run `that-script` from `another-script` and both scripts reside in the same directory. You can generally derive that directory from the value of `$0` in `other-script`.

For instance, if `other-script` is a `zsh` script:

```
bash -- $0:h/that-script
```

If not and assuming `$0` doesn't end in newline characters:

```
bash -- "$(dirname -- "$0")/that-script"
```

The dirname of `$0` may be a relative path. To make it an absolute path, you can do, in zsh:

```
bash -- $0:P:h/that-script
```

Other shells:

```
dir=$(CDPATH= cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P) || exit
bash -- "$dir/that-script"
```

Comment: I have just found the solution. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

`pwd` returns a current directory. Each time you do `cd somedir`, the result of `pwd` changes.

So, if `/bin/bash "$(pwd)/Testing_3.sh"` works fine at startup. Do

```
echo "$(pwd)/Testing_3.sh"
```

The result would the string you need to use in crontab.

Comment: "*a* current directory" (my emphasis), you can only have *one* current directory (there can be many paths to it though).

Comment: **$(pwd)** does not work in my case. **$(dirname "$0")** does work. See my answer.